# DRAMSim2 on GEM5 is only printing refresh command

Tags: memory, arm, gem5

I have successfully setup GEM5 in fs mode and with DRAMSim2 memory type. The command I am using is:

```
build/ARM/gem5.opt configs/example/fs.py --disk-image=/home/prakhar/full_system_2/disks/linux-arm-ael.img --mem-type=DRAMSim2
```

Everything is working fine. Now, I have added some comments in DRAMSim2 code to analyze the flow of code and to study command sequence. Then, I have again compile the ARM system to save the changes.

```
scons build/ARM/gem5.opt
```

Now, when I am running gem5 arm in fs mode again, it is just showing the comments of refresh commands. Like this:

```
6 0----------
refresh...
6 0----------
refresh...
6 0----------
refresh...
6 0----------
refresh...
6 0----------
refresh...
6 0----------
refresh...
6 0----------
refresh...
6 0----------
refresh...
6 0----------
```

Why can't I see other commands like ACT,READ,WRITE etc.There should be some read,write,act even when the OS is booting up?
I have added comments in /gem5/ext/dramsim2/DRAMSim2/MemoryController.cpp

Steps to add DRAMSim2 in gem5:

1. Go to ext/dramsim2 in gem5 directory.
2. Clone DRAMSim2: git clone git://github.com/dramninjasUMD/DRAMSim2.git
3. Re-build the system by scons.
4. Run again in fs mode adding --mem-type=DRAMSim2 at last.

In the ext/dramsim2/DRAMSim2 there is a file MemoryController.cpp.In that file there is a function update().There is a switch-case of different commands like READ,WRITE,ACTIVATE.In respective cases for each command i have added cout like cout<<"read...." in read case, cout<<"refresh..." for refresh case.
Again rebuild the system and run with fs mode and --mem-type=DRAMSim2.
Now i m just getting comments of "refresh...." and not others, but there should be other comments also like "read..." and all as there is some read,write,activate while booting of OS.

Comment: I have never used `DRAMSim2`, what do you mean by "Now, I have added some comments in DRAMSim2 code to analyze the flow of code and to study command sequence."? What have you modified exactly? Possibly edit your patch into the question.

Comment: DRAMSim2 is a simulator of DRAM Memory.Steps to add dramsim2 in gem5: https://github.com/gem5/gem5/tree/master/ext/dramsim2   .Now there is a cpp file MemoryController.cpp in that there is a function update().In that there is a switch-case of functions like READ,WRITE,ACTIVATE in that i have added cout<<"Activate..." and all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was trying yesterday and got the solution.
Initially i was using the command:

```
build/ARM/gem5.opt configs/example/fs.py --disk-image=/home/prakhar/full_system_2/disks/linux-arm-ael.img --mem-type=DRAMSim2
```

In this command the default cpu type is AtomicSimpleCpu , which was only giving refresh commands.Now i have specified cpu type as TimingSimpleCPU and it is giving all commands.

The command is:

```
build/ARM/gem5.opt configs/example/fs.py --disk-image=/home/prakhar/full_system_2/disks/linux-arm-ael.img --mem-type=DRAMSim2 --cpu-type=TimingSimpleCPU
```